# android sqlite listview shows package

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am currently pulling data from my sqlite database using the following query:

```
public List<Catalog> getAllExercise(String ex_class, String period, int age1, int age2, int distance1, int distance2, String vo2max, String language) {
    List<Catalog> exerciseList = new ArrayList<Catalog>();

    String selectQuery = null;
    selectQuery = "SELECT catalog.ex_id, translation.ex_desc, translation.trans_id FROM " + TABLE_CATALOG +", " + TABLE_TRANSLATION + " WHERE catalog.ex_id = translation.ex_id AND catalog.ex_class = " + ex_class + " AND (catalog.age BETWEEN " + age1 + " AND " + age2 + ") AND (catalog.pr_comp_distance BETWEEN " + distance1 + " AND " + distance2 + ") AND translation.language = " + language + ";";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Catalog exercise = new Catalog();
            exercise.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EX_ID)));
            exercise.setExDesc(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EX_DESC)));

            exerciseList.add(exercise);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return exerciseList;
}
```

Very easy function to select the ID and a description field out of my database.

Now I want to show this in a listview using the following code in my onCreate function:

```
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

ListView list_exercises = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_training_sessions);

List<Catalog> exercise = new ArrayList<Catalog>();
exercise = db.getAllExercise(ex_class, period, age1, age2, distance1, distance2, vo2max, "'" + language + "'");
ArrayAdapter<Catalog> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Catalog>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, exercise);

list_exercises.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I get the right amount of results in my list but it is only visible as the following:

```
info.olbrecht.sqlite.model.Catalog@41000dd0
```

I guess this is my package name?

PS: If I use `Log.d` the right values are shown, so I must have made a mistake somewhere in my listView or my conversion to String I guess? Not quite sure...

What am I doing wrong?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayAdapter` uses `toString()` to convert the objects to string representations. You will have to override `toString()` in `Catalog` to get the output you want. The default `Object.toString()` outputs the full class name, an `@` sign and the object hashcode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have no clue how to do this. Could you help me out?

Comment: I don't know what data your `Catalog` has but generally it's something like `@Override public String toString() { return "some string representation"; }`

Comment: Catalog is just all my getters & setters and a `public Catalog( bunch of variables ) { ... }`